# Self Authenticating Usb

Tags: linux, usb, authentication, linux-kernel

Is it possible put a script on a usb that it only allows the contents of a folder to be discovered (or even whole usb to be undiscoverable), unless certain requirements are met?

For example; If I have a folder of sensitive information, I can put this script in the folder, and when the usb gets plugged in all the contents are undiscoverable. 
But, the script is then run immediately to check if it is my computer or not (checks serial number or something) and only then will it allow the folder to be discoverable?

I'm on Linux

Comment: Looks good until your computer is lost/broken/stolen. And of course if you do this you have to do it with all the backups otherwise what would be the point? This makes the loss of the PC even more problematic. Regular encryption has its good sides.

Answer (score 0):

It is not impossible – however, the USB stick's internal controller must be programmed to work this way. You cannot just take any random USB stick and make it lock itself; you must specifically purchase one that already has this feature built in.

USB flash drives with "protected areas" *do* exist (I remember seeing some even back in 2005). Usually this feature is very prominent in the marketing materials, so it should be easy to find some on Amazon or whatever other shopping site.

However:

- The unlock "script" (usually a manufacturer-supplied program) cannot run automatically as soon as the drive is plugged in; the OS simply will not do that. You'll need to manually open and launch the .exe file. (However, some manufacturers' tools can be installed into the computer so that it'll unlock your drive automatically.)
- The unlock program may need Administrator privileges to run (because it sends custom commands to the hardware), i.e. it won't necessarily be usable on public machines.
- Each OS (Windows, macOS, Linux) of course needs its own version of the unlock program – if you have a Mac, better carefully check the drive's compatibility list.